# Unable to open a dialog with a ribbon button

Tags: outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

We have an Outlook web addin with a ribbon button defined in the manifest.

```
                            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeSettingsButton">
                                <Label resid="funcComposeButtonLabel2" />
                                <Supertip>
                                    <Title resid="funcComposeSuperTipTitle2" />
                                    <Description resid="funcComposeSuperTipDescription2" />
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="settings-16" />
                                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="settings-32" />
                                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="settings-80" />
                                </Icon>
                                <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                    <FunctionName>loadSettings</FunctionName>
                                </Action>
                            </Control>
```

The loadSettings function is defined in the function file that is also defined in the manifest.
The loadSettings function calls the displayDialogAsync method from the Office Api.

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
    options.url,
    options.dialogOptions,
    function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
            let errorMessage = null;

            log('ERROR', asyncResult.error);

            // In addition to general system errors, there are 3 specific errors for
            // displayDialogAsync that you can handle individually.
            switch (asyncResult.error.code) {
            case 12004:
                errorMessage = 'Domain is not trusted';
                break;
            case 12005:
                errorMessage = 'HTTPS is required';
                break;
            case 12007:
                errorMessage = 'A dialog is already opened.';
                break;
            default:
                errorMessage = asyncResult.error.message;
                break;
            }

            log('ERROR', errorMessage);
        }
        else {
            _dialog = asyncResult.value;
            _dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, handleDialogMessageEvent);
            _dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, eventReceivedHandler);
        }
    }
);
```

The dialog renders and opens fine in every platform tested (Outlook for Windows and OWA (IE, Firefox, Chrome)) except for a select few on Outlook for Mac. Why does the dialog work as expected for most on Outlook for Mac, but not for a select few?

Comment: Do you mean that it does not work for a select few messages, or a select few build versions? Or does it not work for certain OS versions? If you mean build versions, could you also provide the version(s) for which it does not work?

Comment: Select few users. Same addin version. Same version of Oulook for Mac. Same Mac OS version.

Comment: Just to be clear, does it not work for a few accounts (across devices) or for any user on a few specific devices?

Comment: Only a few users are experiencing the issue on Outlook for Mac. The same few users are able to open the dialog on OWA and Outlook for Windows.

Comment: Any idea what may be going on here? @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility